# Formula with quotes for validation in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Formula not work properly in PHPExcel. 
Try use validation, but get `0` in result file at cell B3: Validity - Sorce

```
    $objValidation = $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B3')->getDataValidation();
    $objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
    $objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
    $objValidation->setAllowBlank(true);
    $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
    $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
    $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
    $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list subcategories');
    $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
    $objValidation->setFormula1('INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($A$3," ","_"))');
```

Similar formula without quotes `$objValidation->setFormula1('INDIRECT($A$3)')` work as expected

Comment: Is $A$3 a reference to a named range? If I'm to try and replicate the issue, I need to know that it isn't an A1 or an R1C1 format cell reference

Comment: Yes $A$3 is a reference to a named range. But even when $A$3 is an empty cell I got same issue.